# Alternative to Apple Books for power users that works across all devices?

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, ebook

I'm quite sick of Apple Books as it randomly deletes books from my library on the iPad, and find myself out of a book exactly when I need it the most and I'm offline. The app also makes it deliberately hard to sync multiple books, one has to click each file one by one.

With Podcasts, I absolutely love Overcast over the default Podcasts app for the amount of control I get with downloading what I need and playing it in the order I need with an intuitive UI. Is there such an alternative for PDF & ePub files that can help me:

- organise books into collections,
- sync across all my devices (ideally over iCloud),
- be available on all devices - macOS, iPadOS, iOS

Very happy to pay for such an app with these basic functionalities built in a way *not* to frustrate the user.

Comment: For people voting to close... why? I'm genuinely trying to find out if there's an app that can help me read books easily on my iDevices - isn't that something the SuperUser community can help with?

Comment: Your asking for a software recommendation.  Question seeking software recommendations are not within scope

Comment: Ouch :( I thought they were - thanks for clarifying. Is there another StackExchange for this? I really love this format for getting answers / reccos...

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you 

Comment: Link in case someone has reccos: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/77245/70641